# Color Points (Bars) in Pivot Chart based on Row Labels (Axis Fields)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I'm trying to automate a process that so far I have been doing manually in Excel 2010.  I create Pivot Charts often.  One of the series on these charts is displayed as bars.  I change the fill color of each bar based on one of the row labels of the pivot chart.  For instance, if the row label = "GEO", I change the fill color of the bar to green.

I'm sure that it's possible to automate this process through VBA.  Here's my code so far.  When I run this macro, it stops at the first line of the If statement and gives this error.  Compile error: Expected array.  Can anyone give me some advice as to how to make this code work?

```
Sub By_Rig_PC_Coloring()

For i = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Points.Count
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Points(i).Select
    If xlRowField("MFR") = "GEO" Then
        Selection.Format.Fill.Forcolor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Try to record your manual actions using macro recorder - this will definitely give you the right way to address objects.

Comment: I tried this method initially, but, I simply select the ActiveChart.SeriesCollection (2).Point(x), where "x" is whatever bar I select.

Comment: Is "Forcolor" also misspelled in the actual code?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot access X axis labels associated with current `Point`. But this is a PIVOT chart, so you can use your pivot table to get the info you need.

Points are DataField's PivotItems, Series are ColumnFields and X labels are RowFields.
So `SeriesCollection(2).Points(10)` will be `pvtYourPivotTable.ColumnFields(2).DataRange.Cells(10)` (assuming that you have only one `DataField`, otherwise `DataRange` will be multi-column, and you'll have to adjust for that).
So once you have a cell in pivot table assosacietd with Point, the label will be located at `Intersect(pvtYourPivotTable.RowFields("MFR").DataRange, pvtYourPivotTable.ColumnFields(2).DataRange.Cells(10).EntireRow`. You can also use `Offset` or other method.

Here is another method of colouring chart bars based on X labels: [Peltier Tech Blog](http://peltiertech.com/create-update-chart-using-partial-pivot-table/) without VBA.

Hope this helps.